# Windows 10: WSOCK32.dll is not designed to run on Windows?

Tags: windows-10

Just recently I've been getting a pop-up on my home screen every time the computer starts that says:

One Drive - Bad Image
C:\Windows\System32\WSOCK32.dll is not designed to run on Windows or contains an error. Error status: 0xc0000020.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the file may be corrupt.  Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and select `Command Propmt (Admin)`.  Then type the following:

> SFC /SCANNOW

Follow the prompts.  This will scan for corrupt Windows files and repair them.

In older versions of Windows, some virus scanners have been known to cause this error.  However, I doubt this is the issue, as you are Windows 10.